# How to trigger a function when trying to submit a form using vazco/uniforms?

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I am trying to call a function when the user clicks on the submit button inside an AutoForm from the [vazco/uniforms](https://github.com/vazco/uniforms) components. I'm also using the parameter schema={schema} to validate if the form data is correct. What happens is if the form is incorrect, I didn't find a way to trigger the function. How can I set it on the AutoForm?

Detail: I need to be just when the user clicks on the button submit of the form.

I have:

```
<AutoForm
   showInlineError
   schema={schema}
   model={model}
   label={false}
   onSubmit={this.submitForm.bind(this)}
>
...
</AutoForm>
```

I know I can write:

`onValidate={(modelTmp, error, callback) => {..}}`

and also

`modelTransform={(mode, model) => {..}}`

but with this functions I don't know if the user just clicked on the submit button, or if he is typing something on the form and it is changing the model.

Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I talked to the creator of the vazco/uniforms, Radosław Miernik, and he said that there are two ways of solving it:

1) Adding a button on the form, when it is clicked, triggers the function.

2) Create a custom form to make it.

As I was looking for a solution to use only AutoForm, I noticed it was not possible. My solution was then to create a custom form with what i needed. So the solution is a Custom Form (based on [AutoForm](https://github.com/vazco/uniforms/blob/master/packages/uniforms/src/AutoForm.js)):

```
import cloneDeep from 'lodash.clonedeep';
import isEqual from 'lodash.isequal';
import set from 'lodash.set';
import {PropTypes} from 'react';


import ValidatedQuickForm from 'uniforms-bootstrap3/ValidatedQuickForm';

const Auto = parent => class Custom extends parent {
    static Auto = Auto;
    static displayName = `Auto${parent.displayName}`;

    static propTypes = {
        ...parent.propTypes,
        onChangeModel: PropTypes.func
    };

    constructor() {
        super(...arguments);// eslint-disable-line

        this.state = {
            ...this.state,
            model: this.props.model,
            modelSync: this.props.model
        };
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps({model}) {
        super.componentWillReceiveProps(...arguments);// eslint-disable-line

        if (!isEqual(this.props.model, model)) {
            this.setState({model, modelSync: model});
        }
    }


    func() {
        // makes whatever i need
    }

    getNativeFormProps() {
        const {
            onChangeModel, // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
            ...props
        } = super.getNativeFormProps();

        return props;
    }

    getModel(mode) {
        return mode === 'form' ? this.state.modelSync : this.state.model;
    }

    onChange(key, value) {
        this.setState(state => ({modelSync: set(cloneDeep(state.modelSync), key, value)}), () => {
            super.onChange(...arguments);// eslint-disable-line
            this.setState({model: this.state.modelSync}, () => {
                if (this.props.onChangeModel) {
                    this.props.onChangeModel(this.state.model);
                }
            });
        });
    }

    onReset() {
        this.setState(() => {
            super.onReset();

            return {
                model: this.props.model,
                modelSync: this.props.model
            };
        });
    }

    onSubmit(event) {
        if (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
        }

        this.func(); // func that i wanted to call

        return new Promise(resolve =>
            this.setState({validate: true}, () =>
                resolve(this.onValidate().then(
                    () => super.onSubmit()))
            )
        );
    }

    onValidate() {
        return this.onValidateModel(this.getChildContextModel());
    }
};

export default Auto(ValidatedQuickForm);
```